# How to restore IBM DB2 database from AIX to Windows?

Tags: backup, windows, db2, restore

I had made backup from remote IBM DB2 server in AIX using this command:

```
./db2 backup database DBEMP to /home/dbemp/backup
```

Then I grab the backup file using FTP Client from my Windows.

I run this command to restore the database in my local machine:

```
./db2 restore database DBEMP from "C:\backup" TAKEN AT 20130521002219
```

But I got this error message:

> SQL2570N  An attempt to restore on target OS "NT-64" from a backup
>   created on source OS "AIX-64" failed due to the incompatibility of
>   operating systems or an incorrect specification of the restore
>   command.  Reason-code: "1".

So what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot restore a DB2 database from AIX into Windows because of the endian. These are not compatible architectures.

For more information, check the InfoCenter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0005960.html

The only way to retrieve the data between these platforms is via db2look + db2move.

- db2look http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html
- db2move http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html

Comment: +1 to answer. We use db2look and db2move where we are. db2move *currently* includes a "look" in it, but this is not guaranteed to stay that way in the future per what I've read from IBM. Use the db2look for the schema and the db2move for your data. We use this to ship developers (who use Windows) schema and data from our AIX systems.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried the db2move to import with replace/replace_create option, but it can't overwrite the existing database, so I had to drop the database first. Is there a command to import and overwrite the database at once?

Comment: db2move includes the DDL for tables (as export files are in IDX format), but not for other objects. This is the reason it is necessary to use db2look (stored procedures, sequences, functions, etc.)

Comment: Is db2lookup and db2move are included in IBM Data Studio? I prefer to do it in GUI tool if possible.

Comment: No, I don't believe they are. They are executable programs (and thus "commands") on the command line for DB2. So these you will have to use command line access for.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich: I mean is whether there is same functionality exist in IBM Data Studio or not. For example, there is backup functionality in IBM DB2 (right click menu on database name) which actually execute `backup database` command at behind.

Comment: @suud - right. And from what I see of Data Studio (we use it where I work), it does not have the ability to execute db2look/db2move intrinsically. I believe you will need to log onto the command line of the database locally or remotely (ie outside of the Data Studio tooling) and execute db2look or db2move.

Comment: Data Studio lets you "copy" a table from one database and "paste" it into another. It works OK for smaller tables, but you don't want to do it for tables with more than few thousand records.

Comment: I think these comments are not part of the original question. If you want to know the options to move a table, please create another question.